# Unable to get points from NetCDF even ogrinfo shows it has data

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, netcdf

I need to extract point data to convert it to GeoJSON from a NetCDF file, the file seems ok when issuing ogrinfo ultimo.nc

```
 INFO: Open of éultimo.nc'
      using driver énetCDF' successful.
Metadata:
  NC_GLOBAL#cdm_data_type=Point
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.7
  NC_GLOBAL#dataset_name=OR_GLM-L2-LCFA_G16_s20221830113400_e20221830114000_c20221830114027.nc
  NC_GLOBAL#date_created=2022-07-02T01:14:02.7Z
  NC_GLOBAL#featureType=point
  NC_GLOBAL#id=9dfe71fc-f92f-459d-8316-dba325747156
  NC_GLOBAL#institution=DOC/NOAA/NESDIS> U.S. Department of Commerce, National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration, National Environmental Satellite, Data, and Information Services
  NC_GLOBAL#instrument_ID=FM1
  NC_GLOBAL#instrument_type=GOES-R Series Geostationary Lightning Mapper (GLM)
  NC_GLOBAL#iso_series_metadata_id=f5816f53-fd6d-11e3-a3ac-0800200c9a66
  NC_GLOBAL#keywords=ATMOSPHERE > ATMOSPHERIC ELECTRICITY > LIGHTNING, ATMOSPHERE > ATMOSPHERIC PHENOMENA > LIGHTNING
  NC_GLOBAL#keywords_vocabulary=NASA Global Change Master Directory (GCMD) Earth Science Keywords, Version 7.0.0.0.0
  NC_GLOBAL#license=Unclassified data.  Access is restricted to approved users only.
  NC_GLOBAL#LUT_Filenames=GLM_CALINR_AllFilters(FM1E_CDRL79RevK_PR_09_00_02)-637824700.0.h5 GLM_SolarGlintParameters(FMAA_CDRL79RevH_DO_08_00_00)-587190369.0.xml GLM_AlignmentParameters(FMAE_INT_ONLY_DO_07_00_00)-600000000.0.xml GLM_BackgroundGain(FM1A_CDRL79RevG_DO_08_00_00)-598329337.0.h5 GLM_CoastlineID_Parameters(FM1E_CDRL79RevH_DO_08_00_00)-600000000.0.xml GLM_DownSamplingLUTs(FMAA_CDRL46RevM_DO_08_00_00)-600000000.0.h5 GLM_BG_Assemble(FMAA_CDRL46RevM_DO_08_00_00)-600000000.0.xml GLM_GSHHS_Data(FM1E_CDRL79RevJ_DO_08_00_00)-585000000.0.h5 GLM_IlluminationMask_PV_LUT(FMAA_CDRL46RevM_DO_08_00_00)-600000000.0.h5 GLMNavigationParams(FM1E_CDRL79RevJ_DO_08_00_00)-593179200.0.xml GLM_L1aDS_CALINR(FMAA_CDRL43RevJ_DO_08_00_00)-600000000.0.h5 AI_GLM-L2-GLMSemiStaticParams(FMAE_CDRL46RevM_DO_09_01_00)-652936750.0.bin
  NC_GLOBAL#Metadata_Conventions=Unidata Dataset Discovery v1.0
  NC_GLOBAL#naming_authority=gov.nesdis.noaa
  NC_GLOBAL#orbital_slot=GOES-East
  NC_GLOBAL#platform_ID=G16
  NC_GLOBAL#processing_level=National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA) L2
  NC_GLOBAL#production_data_source=Realtime
  NC_GLOBAL#production_environment=OE
  NC_GLOBAL#production_site=WCDAS
  NC_GLOBAL#project=GOES
  NC_GLOBAL#spatial_resolution=8km at nadir
  NC_GLOBAL#standard_name_vocabulary=CF Standard Name Table (v35, 20 July 2016)
  NC_GLOBAL#summary=The Lightning Detections: Events, Groups, and Flashes product consists of a hierarchy of earth-located lightning radiant energy measures including events, groups, and flashes. Lightning events are detected by the instrument. Lightning groups are a collection of one or more lightning events that satisfy temporal and spatial coincidence thresholds. Similarly, lightning flashes are a collection of one or more lightning groups that satisfy temporal and spatial coincidence thresholds. The product includes the relationship among lightning events, groups, and flashes, and the area coverage of lightning groups and flashes. The product also includes processing and data quality metadata, and satellite state and location information.
  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_end=2022-07-02T01:14:00.0Z
  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_start=2022-07-02T01:13:40.0Z
  NC_GLOBAL#title=GLM L2 Lightning Detections: Events, Groups, and Flashes
```

but ogr2ogr says the following:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -select flash_lon,flash_lon -nlt POINT datos.json ultimo.nc 
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource éultimo.nc' with the following drivers.
```

I know from a prior Python code that this data exists in the dataset, is there a way to inspect the variables in dataset and get the values?

The file with gdalinfo says is not a known format. But ogrinfo does recognize it.

You can download the NetCDF file from [here](https://cloud1.on.gt/data/test/ultimo.nc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GDAL/OGR system can only cope with spatial data stored in a specific pattern of dimensions in a NetCDF file. The NetCDF file is a flexible file format for any form of structured data, spatial or non-spatial, so OGR can't be smart enough to work out where the coordinates are for every case.

There are standards for spatial data in NetCDF but your one doesn't seem to be written as that (https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/netcdf.html). So I don't think `ogr2ogr` (or any other GDAL/OGR tools/drivers) will cope with it.

You will have to attack it with generic NetCDF tools and understand the data structure (or ask for the documentation of the structure from whoever made it). It seems that the `flash_lon` and `flash_lat` names are *variables* dimensioned by the "dim" of `number_of_flashes`. If you can find a package for your favourite programming language that can read NetCDF then that should be enough info to extract the numbers. For example, in R:

```
> library(ncdf4)
> nc = nc_open("./ultimo.nc")
> ncvar_get(nc,"flash_lon")[1:10]
 [1]  -59.58123 -102.28098  -53.21519 -104.04082  -96.92973  -75.32829
 [7] -104.57798  -46.54314  -81.02259 -102.67152
```

Python packages for reading NetCDF also exist.

Also if you can install the `ncdump` command-line routine then you can ask it to dump the values of variables:

```
ncdump  -v flash_lon,flash_lat ultimo.nc
```

will output a big metadata header and then the values of the variables:

```
flash_lon = -59.58123, -102.281, -53.21519, -104.0408, -96.92973, -75.32829, 
    -104.578, -46.54314, -81.02259, -102.6715, -102.7113, -56.486, -106.6923, 
    -99.79274, -46.27336, -43.07574, -112.0341, -68.94675, -85.70372, 
    -75.09546, -107.3669, -79.31267, -71.18448, -102.4644, -82.31383, 
[etc]
```

which you can then maybe convert to GeoJSON or other format using whatever tools you know best.

Comment: I found a library in Python named GOES that let me extract the values. I thought maybe there is a better way to get this data only using command line GDAL as I do with raster.   Thanks for editing the question @Vince, sorry for my English.